# Loading data from external API in Vega

Tags: vega

When I try to change https://vega.github.io/editor/#/examples/vega/scatter-plot like,

```
-       "url": "data/cars.json"
+       "url": "http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees",
```

I get an error,

> loader.js:166 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://vega.github.io/editor/#/edited' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

How do I fetch data from an external API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple. I just needed to use the same protocol HTTPS --> HTTPS

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v3.json",
  "description": "A scatterplot showing horsepower and miles per gallons for various cars.",
  "data": {"url": "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos"},
  "mark": "point",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "userId","type": "quantitative"},
    "y": {"field": "id","type": "quantitative"}
  }
}
```